# Unable to understand and interpret the result of SQL query

Tags: sql, database

Consider the following relations A, B, C. Can some one please tell the output of the following query. I am unable to interpret it after AUB. Please explain.

[image]

**Table A**

```
Id   Name    Age
----------------
12   Arun    60
15   Shreya  24
99   Rohit   11
```

**Table B**

```
Id   Name   Age
----------------
15   Shreya  24
25   Hari    40
98   Rohit   20
99   Rohit   11
```

**Table C**

```
Id   Phone  Area
-----------------
10   2200   02  
99   2100   01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(A UNION B) JOIN C WHERE A.Id > 40 OR C.Id < 15
```

Sorry , I can't give you a result now becouse I wrote this from my table and I don't have time for it. I think this will help for you to understand it better: [Relational Algebra and SQL](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~kifer/Courses/cse532/slides/ch5.pdf)